# PDO delete all rows with DATE_ADD func doesnt work

Tags: mysql, pdo

Instead of CRON function to clear database from old login attempts i'm trying to use a query to delete all rows with DATE_ADD interval function but it doesn't want to work.

```
$sql = $db->query("DELETE FROM failed_logins 
WHERE last_attempt < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)");
```

tried using NOW() instead of CURDATE() but than it doesn't recognize INTERVAL at all and just deletes everything.

Thats how last_attempt column looks like inside - 2015-01-29 13:33:02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT NOW() as `now`,
              DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AS `now + 15 minutes`,
              DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AS `midnight + 15 minutes`;

+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| now                 | now + 15 minutes    | midnight + 15 minutes |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 2015-01-29 12:54:56 | 2015-01-29 13:09:56 | 2015-01-29 00:15:00   |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Since the values from the column `last_attempt` are probably in the past, it's obvious that `WHERE last_attempt < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)` will select and delete all the rows from the table.

I assume you want to delete the entries **older** than 15 minute; the correct condition uses `DATE_SUB()` to get the timestamp of *15 minutes in the past*:

```
DELETE FROM failed_logins 
WHERE last_attempt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```